# can we verify that boostlog core did remove sink?

Tags: c++, boost-log

I am using boost log to make logging system for my program.
I understand boost log mechanism like this:
the core singleton registers sink ,this leads to raising shared pointer count of sink by 1,then we backend raising this count to 2 in addition to main count of shared pointer of sink as 0 .
In my code I remove sink from core and I expect that shared pointer count of this front end sink is decreased to 1 ,then I test this shared pointer to be unique and if so I reset the shared pointer.
I use multi threads and use mutex to protect boost log code working with this specefic sink" I have cout sink and I do not protect it"
the problem is : sometimes I find that sink front end shared pointer counter is not 2,it becomes 3.
I do not know why this is happening as every sink will be registered to core once making its count 1 then adding backend we should have count of 2 only.
is there any way I can verify that core has removed front end sink??
is there any way to know where each instance of shared pointer is present in code??
thanks alot

Update:
if core.remove_sink is executed on one thread and at the same time core log to cout is done on another thread"cout sink is not protected by mutex" and i can see on console that msg is written in wrong position where certain message after core.remove_sink is ought to be done ,BUT here frontend sink shared pointer count is not reduced!!
Did the core discarded the remove_sink which came at same time of logging to another sink???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way I can verify that core has removed front end sink?

The sink is considered removed when `remove_sink` returns. That is, it will not receive any future log records.

It may not be released by the library at that point because there may be log records in progress at the point of the `remove_sink` call, and `remove_sink` may return before those log records are fully processed. Log record processing will continue and may involve the sink that is being removed. Eventually, when all log records are processed and `remove_sink` have returned, the sink will have been released by the core and, if no more references are left, destroyed.

You can detect when the sink is no longer present by using [`weak_ptr`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#weak_ptr), which you can construct from `shared_ptr` referencing the sink. When the last `shared_ptr` referencing the sink object is destroyed or reset, the `weak_ptr::lock` method will return a null `shared_ptr`. Note that this includes any `shared_ptr`s to the sink that you may be holding in your code.

> is there any way to know where each instance of shared pointer is present in code?

Generally, no. You will have to manually track where you pass and save pointers to objects.

Comment: I put protecting mutex around every call to log class and the error was gone.thanks alot